# How to trick a program into thinking there is no X server running

Tags: x11

I have this program that can run with both a text user interface and a graphical user interface.

It lacks any command line switch to force one or the other, rather I guess it somehow auto-detects whether we are in X or not (e.g. if I run it from a virtual terminal it enters its text mode, and if I run it from an X terminal emulator it opens a separate graphical window).

I'd like to force it into text mode and have it run inside the X terminal. How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Usually just

```
unset DISPLAY
```

in command-line of the terminal.  Some applications are smarter than that, and actually check permissions and type of the console versus pseudoterminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, some really obstinate software will assume `DISPLAY=:0` if it's unset.  I believe you can fix that by running it under a different user and using iptables to drop loopback X11, but that's pretty gross.

Comment: @Kevin maybe `DISPLAY=invalid:0` ?

Comment: no... that would only try to make the program connect to the display on "invalid".  It might not timeout rapidly enough to be useful.

Comment: @ThomasDickey fite me :-). There are two X libraries, and the old one was migrated to be a wrapper for the new low-level one. At least on my machine, `xterm` knows to fail near-instantly on NXDOMAIN.

Comment: If you don't want to leave DISPLAY unset in that shell, you could do `(unset DISPLAY; emacs foo.c)` to do the unset in a subshell for one command or list of commands.

Comment: @PeterCordes or you can execute the command through `env` instead of a subshell: `env -u DISPLAY emacs foo.c`

Comment: @PeterCordes `emacs` does have a command line flag to disable the use of X. Just type `emacs -nw`. But if it didn't, you could instead use `DISPLAY= emacs`, which works as well.

Comment: `DISPLAY=0.0.0.0:0` fails instantly without doing a name server lookup.

Comment: You could also do something like `DISPLAY=:6` if you have problematic software, assuming that display doesn't exist locally.

Comment: @Kevin _"... and using iptables to drop loopback X11"_ - No firewalling required; Xorg/XFree86 have been configured not to listen on the network by default for more than ten years on most distributions. It's all done through Unix Domain Sockets (typically something like `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`).

Answer (score 31):

If you want to disable X for a single command you can write

```
DISPLAY= ./my_command
```

Notice the strategical blank space after `=`.  More generally, you can set environment variables for a process by prefixing your command with a sequence of `<variable>=<value>` separated by spaces.  Since space serves as separator, `=` immediately followed by a space clears the preceding variable.  We can look at the effect of these prefixes by using a subshell as the command and then printing its environment.  Take for instance:

```
$ A=a B=b C= D=d sh
$ echo $A $B $C $D
```

This will print

```
a b d
```

This shows that the environment of the subshell indeed is different as intended.  Note that shell substitution happens before the individual arguments are passed to `echo`.  This means that `echo` will be called with three arguments and so there's only a single space between `b` and `d` in the output, just as if the command line were `echo a b  d` (even though there are two spaces before `d` it only prints single spaces), but unlike `echo a b "" d` (which prints two spaces between `b` and `d`).